# Black Patches on Screen - Graphics Card Issue

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I recently upgraded to 18.04 and since then I am having this weird issue, every time I play game on my machine, I get these black patches on screen. They are not in any fixed location just appear here and there when I open new window or close it etc.

Some sample screenshots:
[image]

[image]

I am guessing this has something to do with my system heating up? But this has never happened before when I was using 16.04. I am not even sure where I should start looking to figure this issue out. Any suggestions?